# Prepare Windows OS image in virtual environment and deploy to real environment

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, deployment, sysprep

I need to prepare some OS typical configurations for my office

I wonder, if it is possible to configure Windows OS (likely 7) in virtual machine, then do a Sysprep, and then deploy it on physical machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. Good thing with Hyper-V is you dont need to install any third party drivers y ou dont need anymore then.

Use WDS to roll out the image and you can have drivers installed AS NEEDED without having them in the image (you only register them in the WDS server). As WIndows current deployments are all image based... that is not bad, neither time nor functionality wise.

Comment: can WDS server cope with Linux deployments?

Comment: thank`s, virtual image deployed without problems

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not.